# exit error in python

Tags: python

```
while True:
   get2=input('Enter: ')
   lst2.append(get2)
   if get2=='':
       break
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
occurs. 
I think this is because the '' for the exit command is not recognized as a integer. How do I '', the enter key, as the exit code AND make sum(list) function work?

Comment: You probably want to check the input value *before* you append it to the list.

Answer (score 2):

You're appending a string and then trying to sum a bunch of strings togethers.

You need to convert them to integers / floating point numbers first so you'd have
`lst2.append(int(get2))` and `lst1.append(int(get1))`

or you could use `float` for floating point numbers

Answer (score 2):

The result of `input` in Python 3 is *always* a string. The `sum` function is then trying to add each item of the list together, starting with 0, so it attempts to to this:

```
0 + your_list[0]
```

But, the first item of your list is a string, and you can't add an integer to a string.

To get around this, convert the input to an integer first by using the `int` function:

```
print('Enter a series of integers. Hit enter to quit')
lst1=[]
lst2=[]

while True:
    get1=input('Enter: ')
    if get1=='':
        break
    lst1.append(int(get1))



while True:
   get2=input('Enter: ')
   if get2=='':
       break
   lst2.append(int(get2))


if sum(lst1)==sum(lst2):
   print('The two lists add up the same')
else:
   print('The two lists do not add up')
```

Note that I've moved the `if` statements before the integer conversion, because otherwise entering `''` will cause an exception to be thrown as an empty string isn't a valid integer.

Comment: @Din No problem. Please remember to accept answers that have helped you!